# A conext menu is shown in a small area instead of full screen on Android Pie

Tags: android

I use a long click context menu. It shown as on the picture:
[image: a normal context menu]

However it is shown in a small area on Android Pie as on the picture:
[image: a small area context menu]

How can I fix the problem?

Since people ask for the code. 
Register for the menu:`registerForContextMenu(listView);`
Open a menu: `@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.listman, menu);
}`

Comment: Please, share your code

Comment: Do you see any error logs in the `LogCat` ?

Comment: Nothing is in the log. All works properly. Only an inconvenience to scroll to menu options.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug for Android 9. If you use AlertDialog for drawing this menu, try setting a theme for it. Or try writing the custom xml yourself for it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the same behavior is for Android 10.